# Namespace routing

Tags: go, beego

I'm new with Go/Beego framework and I'm trying to understand how namespace routing works. I have the following:

```
func init() {

    ns :=
        beego.NewNamespace("/v1",
            beego.NSNamespace("/weather",
                beego.NSInclude(&controllers.WeatherController{}),
            ),
            beego.NSNamespace("/scheduler/weather",
                beego.NSInclude(&controllers.ScheduleController{}),
            ),
        )
    beego.AddNamespace(ns)
}
```

However when I type `127.0.0.1/v1/weather` or `127.0.0.1/weather` on the browser, there's a page not found response. Same with the other url.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
func init() {

ns :=
    beego.NewNamespace("/v1",
        beego.NSRouter("/weather", &controllers.WeatherController{}),
        beego.NSRouter("/scheduler/weather",&controllers.ScheduleController{}),

    )
beego.AddNamespace(ns) }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not on router.go but in the controller definition.

Before:

```
// @router / [put]

func (c *ScheduleController) Put() {
...
}
```

After:

```
// @router / [put]
func (c *ScheduleController) Put() {
...
}
```

The difference was the space in-between `@router` and the method definition.